# XML string not getting serialized properly to C# object

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have the following C# classes.

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://sameplens.com", ElementName = "dataElement")]
public class SampleClass
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "inner")]
    public List<SampleInnerClass> Inner { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "outerfield1")]
    public string OuterField1 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "outerfield2")]
    public string OuterField2 { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class SampleInnerClass
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "innerfield1")]
    public string InnerField1 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "innerfield2")]
    public string InnerField2 { get; set; }
}
```

The XML I'm trying to deserialize looks like this:

```
<ns2:dataElement xmlns:ns2="http://sameplens.com">
  <inner>
    <innerfield1>a1</innerfield1>
    <innerfield2>a2</innerfield2>
  </inner>
  <inner>
    <innerfield1>a3</innerfield1>
    <innerfield2>a4</innerfield2>
  </inner>
  <outerfield1>a</outerfield1>
  <outerfield2>b</outerfield2>
</ns2:dataElement>
```

I have created a generic method for extracting the data:

```
public T ExtractDataFromResponse<T>(string responseString)
{
    T responseObject;
    XmlSerializer responseSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    using (StringReader responseReader = new StringReader(responseString))
    {   
        responseObject = (T)responseSerializer.Deserialize(responseReader);
        return responseObject;
    }
}
```

What I am getting back is a SampleClass type obejct with Inner type List empty, and fields OuterField1 and OuterField2 null. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: [This page](https://json2csharp.com/code-converters/xml-to-csharp) will tell you what your C# model classes should look like to get a proper deserialization.

Comment: You are missing the namespaces.

Comment: @jdweng So adding the namespace to the XmlRoot attribute in my DTO is not enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code get everything.  I child automatically inherits the parent namespace unless otherwise specified.  ns2 is only on the root and not on any children.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SampleClass));

            SampleClass sample = (SampleClass)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
 


    }
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://sameplens.com", ElementName = "dataElement")]
    public class SampleClass
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "inner",Namespace = "")]
        public List<SampleInnerClass> Inner { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "outerfield1", Namespace = "")]
        public string OuterField1 { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "outerfield2", Namespace = "")]
        public string OuterField2 { get; set; }
    }
    public class SampleInnerClass
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "innerfield1")]
        public string InnerField1 { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "innerfield2")]
        public string InnerField2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```